# add subview between tab bar and tab bar items

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I am quite new at making programming designs, and I'm stuck on something.
So I have the following code, where I make a new view, which I actually want to place between my icon and the background from the tabbar.

```
      let tabBarItem1 = myTabBar.items![0] as UITabBarItem
    let tabBarItem2 = myTabBar.items![1] as UITabBarItem
    let tabBarItem3 = myTabBar.items![2] as UITabBarItem
    let tabBarItem4 = myTabBar.items![3] as UITabBarItem

    tabBarItem1.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "image1")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    tabBarItem2.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "image2")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    tabBarItem3.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "image3")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    tabBarItem4.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "image4")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)


    let viewSelected = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(30, 5, 40, 40))
    viewSelected.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    viewSelected.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    //layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    //layer.borderWidth = 2
    viewSelected.layer.masksToBounds = true

    // add subview to tabBarController?.tabBar
    myTabBar.addSubview(viewSelected)
```

Currently, when I add my subview, I get the following result

[image]

The issue is that I want to have this view BETWEEN the icon (which is now behind the view) and the background. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line where you addSubview, by this :

```
myTabBar.insertSubview(viewSelected, belowSubview: myTabBar.subviews.first!)
```

It should do the job!